# Why is Spotlight indexing documents although I disabled documents indexing?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, spotlight

I asked Spotlight not to index Documents, but I keep getting full lists of programming files, like *.c *.h and all kinds of developer files

And its not just in one folder, its all over the place, so I can't use the Privacy filtering to stop this indexing.

How do I stop this? I am using OS X Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are "Developer" items:

I can disable it in System Preferences (16):

[image]

However, I've read that some people can't disable Developer as they don't have the option on forums and what not. I do have an iCloud beta installed, so maybe the public release of Lion doesn't have that option, I'm not sure. I can eliminate all my .m and .h files from popping up.

---

**If you don't have the GUI:**

Navigate to com.apple.spotlight.plist (~/Library/Preferences) (You may need a file revealing app for this, like [this](http://nano8blazex.com/filerevealer/) which I wrote, teehee), open with a text editor, and add right before the `</array>`

```
<dict>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>SOURCE</string>
</dict>
```

If you already have a key value named "SOURCE", replace `<true/>` with `<false/>`. It's probably near the bottom.